# Is there any way to Clear all Cache files programmatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, caching

I'm developing a program that delete the cache of **all programs**. This has been asked many times before but the solutions were either **removed in newer versions** of Android or didn't clear **all** caches or they needed to **root** the device.

I found a solution in [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#user-remove-all-cache-files) that added in **api 30** and should be launched using `Activity#startActivityForResult(Intent, int)` so that the user knows which app is requesting to clear cache.
this action requires `Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in manifests.

I have this permission in my manifest and I using following code in my OnClick method:

```java
Intent clearCache = new Intent();
clearCache.setAction(ACTION_CLEAR_APP_CACHE);
startActivity(clearCache);
```

But it doesn't work in my Android 11 device. Does anyone know code problem?

Thanks.

Comment: "But it doesn't work in my Android 11 device" -- what are you expecting it to do? Note that your `Intent` is not for `ACTION_CLEAR_APP_CACHE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This intent should be launched using
> Activity#startActivityForResult(Intent, int) so that the user knows
> which app is requesting to clear cache.

Check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageManager#ACTION_CLEAR_APP_CACHE).

Use "startActivityForResult" instead of "startActivity":

```
//Get cache dialog
int requestCode = 999;
Intent intent = new Intent(StorageManager.ACTION_CLEAR_APP_CACHE);
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```